# Chrome Extension Maximize Current Window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I understand that directions on how to manipulate windows are found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows).  But I'm having a hard time following along and would greatly appreciate if someone could explain, for example, how to maximize the current window.

I know how to use the chrome.windows functions to create a window, but I'm not sure how to use the same functions to manipulate an existing window.

I know that I need to set [WindowState](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-WindowState) to maximized.  I just cant figure out how to do so inside of an action script.

Comment: It would be better if you posted your best attempt here.  That would give us something to start from.

Comment: I think your issue is probably because the docs layout puts the `type` before the `property`.

The property name is actually `state`, it just looks like `WindowState` because that's listed first, then `state` is concealed by `(optional) state`. Pah!

Answer (score 5):

You could try to use chrome.windows.update:

```
chrome.windows.update(yourWindowId,{state:"maximized"},function(windowUpdated){
    //do whatever with the maximized window
});
```

You can get the window's id using chrome.windows.getCurrent, chrome.windows.getLastFocused or chrome.windows.getAll

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using a multi-monitor setuo, you need to cascade the calls from the creation because the max mode applies where the window is currently located,
therefore, its best to chrome.windows.create in any monitor you may like and then to set the maximized state with the chrome.windows.update.

```
chrome.windows.create(createData, function onCreated(window) {
        console.log('Created');
        chrome.windows.update(window.id, {state:'maximized'}, function onUpdated() {
          console.log('Maximized');
        });
      }
    });
```