# Chrome Update Current Window (unexpected token error)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, window

Chrome's [developer manual](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) states that: "Many functions in the extension system take an optional windowId parameter, which defaults to the current window."

My application creates a new window (lets call it myWindow) in popup state.  While working in this window, the user is likely to end up at another site ("example.com"). My manifest triggers a contentscript.js on loading example.com.  In content.js I want to set the width of myWindow to 1000 (when the user visits example.com).

Thats all background.  But my question is very simple. Why does the following not work:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("example.com") != -1){
    chrome.windows.update(, { width: 1000 });
}
```

It throws the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

in the console.  Which makes sense.  Because there is no content before the "," its not super surprising that it parses as unexpected.  But doesn't the chrome developer manual indicate that the parameter "defaults to the current window?"

So, how do I let it "default" besides not specifying a value?  So how do I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

I've already answered this question in your [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644098/chrome-extension-maximize-current-window) with regard to manipulating Chrome window sizes. Check it out. In that thread, I've mentioned using `chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT` so it looks like:

```
chrome.windows.update(chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT, { width: 1000 });
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work, because it's not valid JS syntax.

If a parameter is called optional in Chrome API docs, you just skip it in the signature. Chrome API examines the total number of parameters and their type (number, string, object) to guess what you meant; the API is arranged in a way that this is unambiguous.

However, that [parameter is **not marked as optional**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update). You have to provide it. Fortunately, the API [provides a constant](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#property-WINDOW_ID_CURRENT) to use in this case:

```
chrome.windows.update(chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT, { width: 1000 });
```

Note: that API is *very* old and this is not consistent with other APIs. For instance, `chrome.tabs` marks `tabId` as truly optional.

Comment: This is not working.  No error is thrown but the window does not update.  There is only one open window, so I don't think it could be targeting the wrong one.  Though perhaps it is targeting some no-longer existing window.

Is there some easy way to add to this, the ability to target the last focused window?

Comment: Is the window maximized? If yes, changing geometry may not work.